# how can i access SQL database from raspberry pi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to access SQL server from raspberry pi using the following query but i am unable to do that.
what is the problem here?

i have tried different tutorial from internet but didn't worked

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
                  server='servername',
                  database='databasename',
                  uid='UserID',
                  pwd='Password')
```

in windows it is working as i expected but not in raspberry pi3

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Desktop/FYProject/Main.py", line 171, in main()
File "/home/pi/Desktop/FYProject/Main.py", line 72, in main pwd='Password')
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Answer (score 1):

> '{SQL Server}'

Is the old Windows ODBC driver.  You need to install the L[inux ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).